# How can i get contact list from gmail or yahoo or rediffmail using C#.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, import-contacts

I am developing a web application using **C#.net and Asp.net.**

There is an option to Bulk invitation to friends.

For This, Logined user can import their Contacts from their email accounts
(like

**Gmail**,

**YahooMail**,

**Rediffmail**,

**Hotmail**,

**AOL**,

**Microsoft Outlook Express**,

**Sify** etc...) Using my Application.

How can i do it?

Answer (score 3):

From Gmail you can query the contacts using the [.Net library for the Google Data Protocol](http://code.google.com/apis/gdata/client-cs.html#Model)

You should look especially at the `Google.Contacts` namespace, which is targeting the `Google Contacts Data API` ( [link](http://code.google.com/apis/contacts/docs/3.0/reference.html) )
.

From Yahoo you can use the [Yahoo Contacts API](http://developer.yahoo.com/social/contacts/). Yahoo APIs use the `Yahoo Query Language` ( [YQL](http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/)).

I have never used it myself, but a google search came up with http://openinviter.com/ which seems like an open protocol to import contacts from various many providers.

Answer (score 1):

try using with  `Google.GData.Contacts.dll`, `Google.GData.Apps.dll`

```
username=your emailid;
password=email password;
app_name="MyNetwork Web Application!";
DataSet ds = GmailContacts.GetGmailContacts(App_Name, username, password);
GridView1.DataSource = ds;
GridView1.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use opencontactsNet.dll to fetch contacts.

```
using OpenContactsNet;
OpenContactsNet.GmailExtract gm = new OpenContactsNet.GmailExtract();
NetworkCredential nw = new NetworkCredential("sainathsagars@yahoo.com", "");
OpenContactsNet.MailContactList ml = new OpenContactsNet.MailContactList();
gm.Extract(nw, out ml);
// Trying to show something
StringBuilder sbMessage = new StringBuilder();
string strcount = (ml.Count + " Contacts : ");
foreach (MailContact mc in ml)
{
    sbMessage.Append(mc.Email + "<hr size='1'/>");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Previously I had such task and I solved it by using this awesome lib [openinviter](http://openinviter.com).
It's developed on php, to use it from C# I wrote simple php REST service. 
Hope it will help you.